# Socket not fetching the first packets

Tags: python, sockets

I am opening a socket in my compute and sniffing the packets that arrive to eth0. I do that with the following code

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(0x0003))
s.bind((args.interface, 0))
while True:
    packet = s.recvfrom(65565)
```

After that, I am processing the variable packet and printing a bit of the ETH header, IP header and UDP header. The tool prints successfully the headers of DNS and SSH packets that I get. After a while, I send a several vxlan packets but it does not fetch the first ones and after some packets it starts to fetch those, however, it loses the first ones (sometimes 4, sometimes 10 but not higher).

For example, here 14 packets from tcpdump on the interface. The VXLAN packets can be seen among the DNS ones (VxLAN have UDP 6633): http://pastebin.com/uhTR4YLb

And here the output of the sniffing tool that I am using for those packets. The DNS packets can be seen but not the VXLAN ones: http://pastebin.com/3L0dL9dy

After 7 VXLAN packets in this example, the vxlan packets are fetched by the sniffer tool. Any idea why the first are not? I am completely lost :(